# How can i use Router of BackboneJs in Html

Tags: html, backbone.js, handlebars.js

As i html with Router link of Angular 4 how can i set Router in that of backboneJS
html is mentioned below

```
            <ul role="menu" class="sub-menu">
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/orderHistory']">History</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/userprofile']">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/addressbook']">Address Book</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/preferences']">Preferences</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['/wishlist']">Wishlist</a></li>
            </ul>
```

I am using backboneJs and Handlersbar any suggestions or good approach would be so useful. Thanks in advance.
I have to make footer and header in my application.

Comment: Why mix Angular and Backbone? Backbone is just in the way of Angular...

Comment: I am not mixing them, I had application Up and running with Angular 4 now clients want on a Backbone Js that is why i want to change it into BackboneJs and HandlersBar

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the `href` of `<a>` as normal hash like:

```
<li><a href="#orderHistory">History</a></li>
```

or if your app supports push state, without the hash like:

```
<li><a href="/orderHistory">History</a></li>
```

and set up and instance of Backbone.Router as mentioned in the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router).
This router instance will listen to changes in url and invoke the callbacks you define while instantiating the backbone router.

Answer (score -1):

You can do following in your backbone.js View

```
events: {
    'click a': 'changeRoute'
},
changeRoute: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr("href");
    router.navigate(href, true);
}
```